# How are lists implemented to be heterogeneous in python?

Tags: python, list, compiler-construction

How are lists implemented to be heterogeneous? I know that a list is a dynamic array of pointers that point to the memory location of the required element but how does this work when the elements the indexes point to are of different sizes.

Does the location the pointer points to contain information about what type  this location holds and if so, how is that kind of information formatted, used, returned?

I understand how [1,2,3] should look in memory but not how [1,2,"abcdefg"] would look in memory.

Comment: The reason pointers are used is that they are (simplifying here) all the same size, so you can have an array of them representing a heterogenous collection.

Comment: How do you imagine that `[1, 2, 3]` looks like in memory?

Comment: I imagine [1,2,3] is 3 pointers next to each other in memory that point to 3 different sections of memory, of 8 bytes each.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is an object in python: As you mention, lists are collections of 'pointers' to the memory location on the objects contained in the list.

As objects, they each know their type, attributes, properties, etc.
They therefore cannot exceed their own memory boundary, and a tally/accounting of the number of pointers pointed at them is invisibly kept by the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective (i.e. how to implement something like this), look up the Abstract Datatype (ADT) concept in C, e.g. [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/Base/yechiel/C-Examples/).